# Das Verb mit »sinken um/auf«?

Tags: meaning

> Die Zahl der Erwerbstätigen wird um fast 10 Millionen auf nur noch 30 Millionen sinken.

Diesen Satz habe ich in einem Modelltest Goethe gelesen. Ist das richtig? Muss es nicht so sein:

> Die Zahl der Erwerbstätigen wird um fast 30 Millionen auf nur noch 10 Millionen sinken.

Comment: Wenn die Zahl von 40 Mio. auf 30 Mio. sinkt ist der erste Satz richtig, wenn sie von 40 Mio. auf 10 Mio. sinkt der zweite.Solange es keine deutlichen Indizien gibt, dass der Autor falsche Zahlen hat oder als sprachlich inkompetent aufgefallen ist, bietet der erste Satz keinen Anlass zu zweifeln. Umsinken oder Aufsinken sind auch keine Verben wie Umschichten oder Aufhäufen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beide Sätze sind grammatisch völlig in Ordnung. Welcher davon richtig ist, hängt davon ab, was du aussagen willst.

Beispiele:

> Dein Punktestand sinkt **um** 4 Punkte

Das bedeutet: Wenn du vorher 20 Punkte hattest, verlierst du jetzt 4 Punkte, und du hast dann am Ende 16 Punkte. Wenn du vorher 9 Punkte hattest, hast du nachher 5 Punkte, weil du 4 Punkte verloren hast.

> Dein Kontostand sinkt **auf** 300 Euro

Das bedeutet: Wenn du vorher 750 Euro hattest, verlierst du jetzt 450 Euro, und du hast dann am Ende 300 Euro. Wenn du vorher 3800 Euro hattest, dann bist du 3500 losgeworden, und hast am Ende eben genau 300.

Also:

- **Sinken um X**
  X gibt den Rückgang an, also die Differenz zwischen vorher und nachher.
- **Sinken auf X**
  X gibt den Endstand an, unabhängig davon, wieviel du vorher hattest, und unabhängig davon, wie groß der Rückgang war.

Wenn beide Angaben vorhanden sind, kannst du dir den Anfangsstand errechnen, er ist die Summe aus Rückgang und Endergebnis:

> Die Zahl der Erwerbstätigen wird um fast 10 Millionen auf nur noch 30 Millionen sinken.

- Vorher: 40 Millionen (errechnet)
- Rückgang: 10 Millionen
- Endstand: 30 Millionen

---

> Die Zahl der Erwerbstätigen wird um fast 30 Millionen auf nur noch 10 Millionen sinken.

- Vorher: 40 Millionen (errechnet)
- Rückgang: 30 Millionen
- Endstand: 10 Millionen

Answer (score 1):

Eine Zahl sinkt *um* eine *Menge.*

Eine Zahl sinkt *auf* ein *Niveau.*

Jede kann richtig sein.

Answer (score 0):

Das kommt darauf an, was der Fall ist.
Handelt es sich um eine apokalyptische Zukunftsprognose?

Jedenfalls ist der Sinn der Ausdrücke jeweils dieser:
Sinkt ein Betrag *um* X, ist X der Subtrahend.
Der Wert Y, *auf* den der Betrag sinkt, ist der Differenzwert.